# Weird behavior on bash variables

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, ssh, environment-variables

I have the following situation where I try to use following script in order to access my jenkins environment on the specified SSH port in one of my scripts.

However for some reason the variable has some strange behavior with the variable.

When echoing the variable it looks normal.
When echoing the variable in a string it is not shown unless it is at the end of the string
When using the variable in a ssh command it messes up the whole ssh command.

What am I missing? What can I do to further troubleshoot?

```
$ ssh_port=$(curl -vsL http://localhost/login 2>&1 | grep 'X-SSH-Endpoint' | cut -d':' -f 3)
$ echo $ssh_port
44149
$ echo "${ssh_port} jenkins port"
 jenkins port
$ echo "Jenkins port ${ssh_port}"
Jenkins port 44149
$ ssh -p $ssh_port localhost
'ad port '44149
```

UPDATE:

As suggested in the comments I tried following 2 commands to troubleshoot.

```
$ printf %s "$ssh_port" | xxd
00000000: 3434 3134 390d                           44149.
$ od -c <<<"$ssh_port"
0000000   4   4   1   4   9  \r  \n
0000007
```

Are there any suggestions on an approach to achieve what I want without having these strange characters?

Comment: You might have `\r` in your variables. Use `declare -p ssh_port`

Comment: ...and if the output of `declare` looks messed up, then that's more evidence to suggest a carriage return. You can also use `od -c <<<"$ssh_port"` which should show the characters in your variable.

Comment: `printf %s "$ssh_port" | xxd` can help too...

Comment: You can strip the `\r` in parameter expansion, though it's not completely obvious: `"${ssh_port//$'\r'}"` (or, to remove the CR+LF pair, `"${ssh_port//$'\r\n'}"`).

Comment: See the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for advice on dealing with DOS line endings (CRLF, which are also used as part of network protocols).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confirmed that you've got a carriage return inside the variable.

In bash, or any POSIX shell that supports ANSI C (format) expansion, you can solve this easily like this:

```
$ ssh_port=$'44149\r'
$ od -c <<<"$ssh_port"
0000000    4   4   1   4   9  \r  \n
0000007
$ new_port="${ssh_port%$'\r'}"
$ od -c <<<"$new_port"
0000000    4   4   1   4   9  \n
0000006
```

The `${variable%text}` expands to the content of `$variable` with `text` removed from the end of the string, and `$'\r'` is of course a newline.

You could alternately remove the carriage return in the pipeline that populates your variable:

```
$ ssh_port=$(curl -vsL http://localhost/login 2>&1 | tr -d '\r' | sed -ne 's/^X-SSH-Endpoint: [^:]*://p')
```

or even,

```
$ read ssh_port < <(curl -vsL http://localhost/login 2>&1 | grep '^X-SSH-Endpoint:' | grep -E -o '[0-9]+')
```

Finally, parameter expansion alone could isolate the numeric part of the line:

```
$ while read t; do [[ $t == X-SSH-Endpoint:* ]] && ssh_port="${t//[^0-9]/}" && break; done < <(curl -vsL http://localhost/login 2>&1)
```

Or if you want to consider headers and their values as separate variables, and allow for the possibility of hostnames that contain digits:

```
$ while read h v; do [[ $h == X-SSH-Endpoint: ]] && { v="${v#*:}"; ssh_port="${v//[^0-9]/}"; break; }; done < <(printf 'one\r\n%s\nthree\r\n' "$s")
```

So many options.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
ssh_port=$(curl -vsL http://localhost/login 2>&1 | sed '
    /X-SSH-Endpoint/!d         # replace grep
    s/\r$//                    # remove line ending CR
    s/.*://                    # remove up to last colon
')
```

Comment: This gives me an empty value.

Comment: Ok now it shows me the whole thing Grep was already showing me without the things I was doing using cut -d':'

Comment: Too early in the morning. There was an extra asterisk in the last pattern

Comment: In case folks don't notice the `linux` tag on the question, it would be good to point out that this solution depends on GNU sed, and won't work in BSD or macOS.

Comment: What's GNU specific here?